# What is the difference between File(), PhysicalFile(), PhysicalFileResult() in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to build a Web API endpoint using ASP.NET core 3.1 what would allow an application to send me an id, and the response would be with the corresponding file.

Here is my method

```
[HttpGet("get")]
public IActionResult Get(Guid id)
{
    FoundFileInfo file = PathFinder.Get(id);

    if(file == null || !System.IO.File.Exists(file.Fullname))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return File(file.Fullname, "image/jpeg");
}
```

using the same code, I can return `File(file.VirtualName, "image/jpeg")`, `new PhysicalFileResult(filename, "image/jpeg")`, or `PhysicalFile(filename, "image/jpeg")`. But what is the difference between them and what is the right use case for each?

My end goal is to allow the consumer to construct an instance of [IFileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.ifileinfo?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) from the response of my endpoint. Somehow I would want to give the consumer enough info like `LastModified`, `Length`, `Name`, `PhysicalPath`. Which method is the right method to use for my case?

Comment: There are no existing functions that will return a file with all of its metadata the way you are requesting. You'll have to write something that returns the metadata, along with the file data itself, using JSON or some other format. Your client will need to be able to parse that metadata and data to construct a `FileInfo` themselves.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

.NET Core's [`File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-3.1) handles only virtual paths (relative within your website). The [`PhysicalFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.physicalfile?view=aspnetcore-3.1) handles physical (absolute) file paths.

`PhysicalFile` is just a facade that returns the `PhysicalFileResult`. But you can just return it manually with `new PhysicalFileResult`.

I don't think there are other differences, the choice depends then mostly on how are you able to obtain the location of the file you want to return. If you have both a virtual and physical location, you can pick any of the two (`File` or `PhysicalFile`).

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.physicalfileresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0) the `PhysicalFile` variants can be more efficient by `using mechanisms provided by the host.` which means [TransmitFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-transmitfile) on Windows and [sendfile](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) on Linux.