# How is PhysicalFileProvider supposed to work in asp.net controllers

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5, kestrel-http-server

Please consider the following (part of) IApplicationBuilder and IWebHostEnvironment configuration:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "WebContent")),
    RequestPath = "/WebContent"
});
```

In my controller I'm testing 3 different approaches:

```
return LocalRedirect("~/WebContent/index.html");
```

This works, but I'm struggling with the next two and wonder why they fail:

```
return PhysicalFile("~/WebContent/index.html", "text/html");
```

Throws: FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\ProjectPath>\bin\Debug\net5.0~\WebContent\index.html'.

```
return File("~/WebContent/index.html", "text/html");
```

Throws: FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: ~/WebContent/index.html

How do I access/serve the static files from the latter two?

I'm getting nuts iterating variations of the input, so a little background would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @noontz,any update about this case?

Comment: nope... I'm still struggling..  I've tried your solution but it does not work in the context I have.. I should probably be more specific in my question..  I'll be back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
       var path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "WebContent/index.html");
       return PhysicalFile(path, "text/html");
    }
```

Comment: This works if I use "WebContent\\index.html"..  Other things are preventing it to be used in my context, and I would have loved an explanation on the difference between File and PhysicalFile, but I'll mark it as answer ;)

Comment: I see a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546230/what-is-the-difference-between-file-physicalfile-physicalfileresult-in-a) may helpful,Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I'm wondering why File doesn't work in my case after reading the linked post..